# Spark application log4j log file not created

Tags: apache-spark, log4j

I am running a spark application . My application has some log statements.

I want to store the logs as a file in a Linux directory .

Below is my log4j file

When I run the spark job , it  gets launched and finished successfully , but logs are not stored as file, I see a directory logs  gets created inside  /home/cloudera . but I don't see omega.log created

**log4j.properties**

```
# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console, file
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n


# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/cloudera/logs/omega.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
```

Could someone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that /home/cloudera/logs exists in every node, then try adding the next properties to the spark-submit cmd

```
spark-submit
  --master yarn-cluster
  --files /path/to/log4j-spark.properties
  --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-spark.properties"
  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-spark.properties"
  ...
```